# how can calculate discrete value of $sinc^2x$

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, periodic-functions

how to calculate discrete values of $sinc^2x = sin^2x/x^2$ in general form? what if x is odd (certainly function parameter will not be an integer)? can it be calculated as some coefficients of $\pi$ ?
$$
sinc^2(x/2)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x= 0\\ 
0 & \text{ if } x= \pm 2,\pm 4,\pm 6, ..., 2k+2\\ 
? & \text{ if } x= \pm 1,\pm 3,\pm 5, ..., 2k+1
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In the following links there are many information about the function $sinc(x)$ and it's values:

[Definition of Sinc function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133843/definition-of-sinc-function?r=SearchResults)
(another question with complete answers)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function
(the wikipedia article)

Hope that's helping you.